# Can't include relative JS file from layout

Tags: templating, frontend

I'm trying to include the videojs.thumbnails.js file in my layout.html:

```
<script src="./videojs.thumbnails.js"></script>
```

It's located at the same level.

[image]

I am getting the following error: http://localhost:3000/videojs.thumbnails.js 404 (Not Found)

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is all happening in Craft's template folder, where anything with an underscore—like your _layout directory and its contents—won't be accessible via URL.

You'll definitely want to adjust your project layout to keep Craft's templates together in /craft/templates, and any front-end resources (like your videojs.thumbnails.js, thumbnails.png, etc.) in the /public folder.

The [Routing documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing) fully explains what Craft does with any front-end URL it gets—it's a tad intense but should fully explain what happens with a request.